# XSL template match based on another element's attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been successfully finding and replacing an XML tag with XSL, but have found an occurrence where my XSL may not work.

Source XML:

```
<article>
    <parastyles>
        <parastyle name="Headline Bold" uid="876"/>
        <parastyle name="Head babies-recipe" uid="877"/>
        <parastyle name="Byline Paper" uid="885"/>
        <parastyle name="Byline Name" uid="886"/>
        <parastyle name="Body Copy" uid="904"/>
    </parastyles>
    <charstyles>
        <charstyle name="[None]" uid="103"/>
    </charstyles>
    <story name="body">
        <runs>
            <run p="886" c="103">By AUTHOR NAME
                <eol/>
            </run>
                <run p="885" c="103">Local Writer
                <eol/>
            </run>
            <run p="904" c="103">CITY — Borough Police en
                <eol hyphenated="true"/>
                countered three men in separate cases
                <eol/>
                recently who all claimed they had for
                <eol hyphenated="true"/>
                gotten they were carrying drugs or drug
                <eol/>
                paraphernalia until an officer started
                <eol/>
                asking questions.
            </run>
            <run p="877" c="103">
                Forgot joints
                <eol/>
            </run>
            <run p="904" c="103">
                In another case, City
                <eol/>
                Police were called to a home
                <eol/>
                on LaSalle Street March 30
                <eol/>
                for a report of a man banging
                <eol/>
                on the door.
                <eol/>
            </run>
            <run p="877" c="103">
                Forgot pipe
                <eol/>
            </run>
            <run p="904" c="103">
                In a third case, Ptlm. Raf
                <eol hyphenated="true"/>
                ferty spotted a young man
                <eol/>
                running along West Second
                <eol/>
                Street and ducking into an
                <eol/>
                area near the Salvation Army
                <eol/>
                drop-off on March 28 around
                <eol/>
                1:40 a.m.
                <eol/>
            </run>
        </runs>
    </story>
</article>
```

My XSL was as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="run[@p='877']">
    <xsl:text>&lt;strong&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&lt;/strong&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This wrapped the selected line with the desired  tag. However, what I really need is to wrap any lines with a  that has a name of "Head babies-recipe" with . Thus far, they have all had a uid of "877" and using run[@p='877'] has worked. However there could be an instance were the uid is NOT "877". So need my 'match' statement to look for a  where p is equal to the the uid of a parastyle where the name is "Head babies-recipe". That's a little more complicated and I've not been able to come up with working XSL for that.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like that (for "Byline Name"):

```
run[@p=/article/parastyles/parastyle[@name='Byline Name']/@uid]
```

Comment: Thanks! Final XSL for my situation is:

    `<xsl:template match="run[@p=/article/parastyles/parastyle[@name='Head babies-recipe']/@uid]">
        <xsl:text>&lt;strong&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&lt;/strong&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>`